# Trying to fetch all data from a webservice in one call

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I have a web service of materials and I'm trying to fetch ALL my materials from that ws. Each ws response brings me a JSON with 20 registers and have a "next" attribute that indicates the next url to consume. I put the request on a 'while' block but it isn't working.

I tried to use semaphores (first time using) to solve the problem with the while block but my app is getting stucked when it arrives there.

How can I fetch all the materials in this case?

The logic is simple:

> while all materials i'nst fetched yet: 
>   bring more 20 materials;
>   Update the screen;

**EDIT:**

WebApi.sharedInstance.fetchDataFromWS() is a call to Alamofire.request()

```
  func loadMaterials() {
    WebApi.sharedInstance.fetchDataFromWS(webservice: .materials, codeToFilterRequest: nil, completion: {
      (json) in

      for item in json["results"] {
        Materials.materials.append(Material.deserializeJson(json: item.1))
      }
      self.collectionView.reloadData()

      let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
      while (json["next"].string != "") {
        WebApi.sharedInstance.fetchDataFromWS(url: json["next"].string!, completion: {
          (json) in

          for item in json["results"] {
            Materials.materials.append(Material.deserializeJson(json: item.1))
          }
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
          (semaphore).signal()
        })
        (semaphore).wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func loadMaterials(url: String) {

   webApi.sharedInstance.fetchDataFromWS(webservice: .materials, codeToFilterRequest: nil, completion: {(json) in

        for item in json["results"] {
           Materials.materials.append(Material.deserializeJson(json: item.1))
        }

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.loadMaterials(url: json["next"].string)
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this. The only difference is that I'm using AlamoFire instead of URLSession directly. That parting of bring the first JSON is working. My problem is trying to keep doing the requisition until I get all the data.

Comment: Ohh okok im sorry. I didnt understand your question. Maybe you can do a function that recives url string and do the request. Everytime it finish calls again the same function with a given url. Im correct? or i dont understand yet?

Comment: I just updated the question text. The problem is: I have 1000 materials on my DB, my ws only brings me 20 at time. I need to make various request until I have those 1000 registers, but I'm having troubles with that while block.

"Everytime it finish calls again the same function with a given url. Im correct? or i dont understand yet?" EXACTLY!

Comment: Ok, you want to update ui every time you get 20 materials or just when you have all of them?

Comment: each time I get 20.

Comment: i updated my answer. each time it has a json, save in array, then update ui and then request again. I didnt handle when all 1000 materials are loaded but i think it works just need to add that